# Disable web security in Cypress just for one test

Tags: automated-tests, cypress, end-to-end, browser-testing

After reading the Cypress [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security.html#Disabling-Web-Security) on web security and when to disable it, I've decided I indeed need to do it. Is there a way to disable this just for one particular test/test suite? I'm using **version 3.4.1** and this config is being set in `cypress.json` - therefore it's global for all tests.

**Is there a way to disable web security just for one test? Thanks!**

Answer (score 1):

**Original answer:**

Does this work for you?

```
describe("test the config json", function () {
    it("use web security false here", function () {
      Cypress.config('chromeWebSecurity',false);
      cy.visit("https://www.google.com");
      console.log(Cypress.config('chromeWebSecurity'));
    });

    it("use web security true here", function () {
      Cypress.config('chromeWebSecurity',true);
      cy.visit("https://www.google.com");
      console.log(Cypress.config('chromeWebSecurity'));
    });
  });
```

The config is changed as you can see from the console log. 
[image]

See document here https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Cypress-config

**Updates:**

After I saw DurkoMatKo's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/102530488?noredirect=1) I managed to find an URL to test this 'chromeWebSecurity' option. It did not work as expected. 
I think changing this config might not work during running the same browser as this is more like a browser feature which will determine when start.
In this case what I can think of is only to run Cypress with different configurations.

The cypress doc [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/configuration-api.html#Promises) shows clear steps to do this. 
hope this helps.

Comment: Wow! Will try it today in the evening and let you know. thanks!

Comment: Thank's for your time, but it doesn't seem to work :/ I still get the cross-origin error. If I disable it using `cypress.json`, then I don't get the error anymore.

Comment: Apologise that I did not have a valid url to test. I think you are right. The config is changed but not applied on the running cypress. I have not found an ideal way to do it. I updated my answer for only a workaround. Please let me know too if you have a better solution. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'll go in the direction you pointed me (multiple config files). Is is fine with you if I don't accept the answer as we didn't find the solution to disable websecurity on the fly for just one test? Maybe someone will come in the future and once it's possible and will answer it...Not sure how SO rules are in such scenario

Comment: In my case it if works. but I need to set the `cypress.json` file with `{"chromeWebSecurity": false}` so in my test change the setting to "true" with `Cypress.config('chromeWebSecurity',true);`

Comment: @Jasp402 could you elaborate, I have `{"chromeWebSecurity": false}` in my `cypress.json` and try to toggle the flag with `Cypress.config('chromeWebSecurity', true);` either in `context` or `it` without success.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to turn it off for all the tests, I've edited cypress.config.ts and added chromeWebSecurity: false. But still when I click a button that opens google sign in page, cypress throws an error saying: Cypress detected a cross origin error happened on page load:

> Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:3000" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Before the page load, you were bound to the origin policy:

> http://localhost:3000

A cross origin error happens when your application navigates to a new URL which does not match the origin policy above. What to do?

Comment: This does not work today. I get error: `Argument of type '"chromeWebSecurity"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof TestConfigOverrides'. ts(2345)`

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked as follows. 
the first thing was to set `chromeWebSecurity` to `false`

```
//cypress.json 
{
"chromeWebSecurity": false
}
```

Then what I do is with a before assign it to `true` with `Cypress.config`

```
    //cypress/integration/testing.spec.js
    context('DEMO-01', () => {
    beforeEach(function () {
        Cypress.config('chromeWebSecurity', true);
    });
    describe('CP001 - start dasboard', () => {
        it('P01: open dashboard', () => {
            cy.visit(URL);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The other comment suggests the same if I'm not mistaken, or? I tried it back then and it didn't work. But times might have changed :D Thx for ur time! :)