# Cypress net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE 6.8.0

Tags: cypress

When I load the page it makes a call to my api `https://<apiurl>/products`. In cypress this request fails with:

```
GET https://<apiurl>/products net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

If I copy the cURL request the response comes back fine. I double checked the headers coming back from the api and there's no cors issue. Nothing is stubbed this is the entire test:

```
describe('Plans page', () => {
  it('should load', () => {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:8001/plans')
    expect(1).to.eq(1)
  })
})
```

```
"cypress": "6.8.0",
```

Comment: found the answer in this other answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58048082/disable-web-security-in-cypress-just-for-one-test

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was caused by the corporate proxy. I had to add [proxy configuration](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/proxy-configuration#Set-a-proxy-on-Linux-or-macOS). (I had exactly same error: *net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE*)

Linux:

```sh
export http_proxy=http://...
export https_proxy=http://...
export NO_PROXY=...

cypress open
```