# How to disable chromeWebSecurity in a certain test suite, in cypress

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

I am using cypress, and I want to disable chromeWebSecurity in test cases, but dont want change cypress config.

before each:

```
beforeEach('before test', () => {
        Cypress.config('chromeWebSecurity',false);
        cy.createUser('type').then((response) => {
            ssoId = response.id;
            phone = response.phone;
        });
    });
```

If I add ""chromeWebSecurity": false" in cypress config (cypress.json) - it works, but i dont want disable this in all my test suites.

I’m trying to add "Cypress.config('chromeWebSecurity',false);" before "cy.createUser('type').then((response) => {" in before each like this:

```
beforeEach('before test', () => {
        Cypress.config('chromeWebSecurity',false);
        cy.createUser('type').then((response) => {
            ssoId = response.id;
            phone = response.phone;
        });
    });
```

but it doesn’t work

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/q/58048082/802365

Answer (score -2):

According to [cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Test-Configuration), you can add it as an option to the `describe` or `it`:

```
describe(
    'login',
    {
        chromeWebSecurity: true
    },
    () => {
        it('With webSecurity', () => {
            // ...
        })

        it('Without webSecurity',
            {chromeWebSecurity: false},
            () => {
            //...
            }
        )
    }
)
```

Comment: `chromeWebSecurity` is *not* in the list of option you can change

Comment: This does not work today. I get error: `Argument of type '"chromeWebSecurity"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof TestConfigOverrides'. ts(2345)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58048082/disable-web-security-in-cypress-just-for-one-test#comment135850385_58053162