# Disable Chrome Web Security for Cypress Testing

Tags: cypress, websecurity

As A tester I am testing a s/w suite.
I have multiple tests where 1 test requires chromeWebSecurity to be true and another test that requires chromeWebSecurity(iFrames CORS error) to be false.
So I want to be able to change chromeWebSecurity before the test starts and not in Cypress.json.

```
cy.log(Cypress.config("chromeWebSecurity"));
Cypress.config("chromeWebSecurity", false);
cy.log(Cypress.config("chromeWebSecurity"));
```

I have already tried the above bit and it changes chromeWebSecurity while logging but does not run the test successfully.

Comment: `Cypress.config("chromeWebSecurity", false);` this command looks correct. Please add your complete test.

Comment: `Cypress.config("chromeWebSecurity", false)` has no effect once a test run has started.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change chromeWebSecurity dynamically, but you can use a specific config file when running the tests, so you can have for example two cypress.config.js files, one with chromeWebSecurity disabled and the other without the flag, like this:
cypress.config.web-security-disabled.js
cypress.config.web-security-enabled.js

and then run two commands like this:

```
npx cypress run --spec 'cypress/e2e/your-spec-who-needs-web-security-enabled' --config-file cypress.config.web-security-enabled.js

npx cypress run --spec 'cypress/e2e/your-spec-who-needs-web-security-disabled' --config-file cypress.config.web-security-disabled.js
```

Of course you can inform multiple specs in the command, so when you run the command above, cypress will execute those specs using the specific config file you want :)

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to change the Cypress config ***object*** during a test by using

```js
Cypress.config("chromeWebSecurity", false)
```

this change does not work because this config item is used during browser startup.

Try to refactor the test that gives you the CORS error.

If it's a login scenario, you may be able to `cy.request()` instead of visiting the login page, or perform the login visit in a `beforeEach()` with a `cy.session()` to preserve the login token.

Comment: This does not work today. I get error: `Argument of type '"chromeWebSecurity"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof TestConfigOverrides'. ts(2345)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58048082/disable-web-security-in-cypress-just-for-one-test#comment135850385_58053162